# Recurrence relation, how to handle fractional terms?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence

So I need to find a_30 for a recurrence relation defined by:

a_n=2*a_n/2 + 1
a_1=1

Underscores dictate subscripts.
The dilemma I run into: in order to find a_30, I must find a_15, but to find that I need a_7.5, which simply doesn't exist. How do I handle this? I also tried running it in Matlab, but it predictably terminated on a_3, citing the same type of nonexistent index.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that your domain is all natural numbers I think that your recurrence relation only exists on n values that are powers of 2, otherwise you will get an index that is fractional and cannot be defined. If you define your relation to be a_n//2, which is the floor(a_n/2) your relation would exist for all n that are natural numbers: (0 or 1, 2, 3, 4, ...)

Comment: Yes, I recognize this. However, the problem only specifies the relation and the base case, and requests a_30. Hopefully the professor will clarify how she wishes to handle this problem.